# Access list within the Model class of Json file in Flutter

Tags: json, list, flutter

I'm trying to access a list within my bean class from the home screen. Bean class created to pull JSON data from an API. My bean class is cars and I'm getting data from a list named 'datalist' which is another list in the JSON data. but I'm getting a runtime error as "Invalid value: Valid value range is empty :0". Please take a look at my code let me know how can I resolve this. thanks in advance

Error is generated from this line in the home screen.

```
 title: Text( snapshot.data[index].datalist[index].title
```

My home file as follows:

```
    body: Container(

        child: Column(

          children: [
///////// Future Builder checks the API service getusers() future method every refreshed time
            Expanded(child: FutureBuilder(
              future: apiService.getCars(),
              builder: (context , snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasData)
                {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index){

                        ////// User List item button

                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CarDetails(
                                car: snapshot.data[index].datalist[index].title,

                              )),
                            );

                          },
                          child:
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow( color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                                  spreadRadius: 5,
                                  blurRadius: 7,
                                  offset: Offset(0, 5),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10 , vertical: 10),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10 , vertical: 10),
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text( snapshot.data[index].datalist[index].title  , style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18,color: Colors.black
                              ),),
                              subtitle: Text( 'car Name', style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18,color: Colors.black
                              ),),
                 
            
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                }else{
                  //////// Loading Circle from Spinkit Plugin
                  return Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: SpinKitCircle(
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            ))

          ],
        ) ,
      ),
```

This is my bean class(car.dart)

```
 import 'dart:convert';

Car carFromJson(String str) => Car.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String carToJson(Car data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Car {
  Car({
    this.status,
    this.data,
  });

  int status;
  List<Datum> data;

  factory Car.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Car(
    status: json["status"],
    data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "status": status,
    "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Datum {
  Datum({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.address,
    this.postcode,
    this.phoneNumber,
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
    this.image,
  });

  int id;
  String title;
  String description;
  String address;
  String postcode;
  String phoneNumber;
  String latitude;
  String longitude;
  Image image;

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
    id: json["id"],
    title: json["title"],
    description: json["description"],
    address: json["address"],
    postcode: json["postcode"],
    phoneNumber: json["phoneNumber"],
    latitude: json["latitude"],
    longitude: json["longitude"],
    image: Image.fromJson(json["image"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "title": title,
    "description": description,
    "address": address,
    "postcode": postcode,
    "phoneNumber": phoneNumber,
    "latitude": latitude,
    "longitude": longitude,
    "image": image.toJson(),
  };
}

class Image {
  Image({
    this.small,
    this.medium,
    this.large,
  });

  String small;
  String medium;
  String large;

  factory Image.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Image(
    small: json["small"],
    medium: json["medium"],
    large: json["large"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "small": small,
    "medium": medium,
    "large": large,
  };
}
```

This is my get cars method and the JSON response body

```
Future<List<Car>> getCars() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiUrl));

    ///// checking the status code is successful
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     
      return getCarList(response.body);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Unable to fetch data from API');
    }
  }

 List<Car> getCarList(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = json.decode(responseBody);
    final List<dynamic> cars= parsed["data"];
    return (cars.map((json) => Car.fromJson(json)).toList());
  }
```

Comment: Could you show the getCars() method and the Json response body.

Answer (score 1):

There is no field called datalist therfore change error causing line as follows.

```
 title: Text( snapshot.data[index].data[index].title
```